# Converting age and sex variables to a 64-unit dense layer

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, papers, embeddings

I am studying a preprint for my own learning (https://www.medrxiv.org/content/medrxiv/early/2020/04/27/2020.04.23.20067967.full.pdf) and I am befuddled by the following detail of the neural network architecture:

[image: architecture_snippet]

This is in accord with the paper's description of the architecture (p. 5):

> Age and sex were input into a 64-unit hidden layer and was concatenated with the other branches.

How can the two scalars of age and sex be implemented as a 64-unit dense layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert them into numbers (using one-hot vectors or direct numerical representations) and then concatenate them. Then, you can pass them through the Dense layer.

Comment: So, I create a dense component with an input vector of size two, which immediately fans out to a fully connected layer of 64 nodes? What would the benefit of that be? I don't see what advantage this holds over just having a node for the sex and a node for the age.

Comment: It will model the relationship between sex and age. You can reduce the number of units though.

Comment: That makes sense, in classical modeling there's a max of 1 interaction but I would suspect 3 nodes is all a person needs.